# Why does va_list var-arg copy not work as expected if the copy is saved and given to another thread?

Tags: c, pthreads, variadic-macros

As in this example, if I call tsub directly from main, output is as expected. If pthread mode is enabled for tsub, this doesn't give expected output.

```
va_list vobj;

void *tsub (void *arg)
{                     
    printf ("vobj: %d, %f\n", va_arg (vobj, int), va_arg (vobj, double));  
    return NULL;  
}               

void print_mydb (char *name, ...)
{        
    va_list ap;  
    va_start (ap, name);  
    va_copy (vobj, ap);  
    va_end (ap);                                                            
}                                 

int main (void)
{              
    pthread_t tid;              
    print_mydb ("b10", 6, 5.23);  

#if 1                           
    printf ("THREADY!!!!!\n");  
    pthread_create (&tid, NULL, tsub, (void *)vobj);  
    pthread_join (tid, NULL);  

#else                        
    tsub (NULL);  

#endif           
    return 0;   
}
```

Output for direct tsub call:

```
vobj: 6, 5.230000
```

Output for pthread invocation for tsub:

```
THREADY!!!!!
vobj: 0, 0.000000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AFAICS](https://www.acronymfinder.com/As-Far-As-I-Can-See-(AFAICS).html), you're invoking undefined behaviour both times; it just sometimes works (seems to work in this context) and sometimes doesn't.  When `print_mydb()` returns, the copied `vobj` is pointing at invalid data — the function call that provided the data (argument list) it points at has returned, so the content of `vobj` is now meaningless.  It doesn't matter whether you call `tsub()` directly or via `pthread_create()`, you're abusing memory once passed to `print_mydb()`.  It breaks worse when `pthread_create()` tramples on the memory as it is called.

Further, the function that calls `va_copy()` *must* call `va_end()` on the copied list before it returns. [C11 §7.16.1 Variable argument list access macros ¶1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.16.1p1)

> Each invocation of the `va_start` and `va_copy` macros
>   shall be matched by a corresponding invocation of the `va_end` macro in the same
>   function.

Consequently, `print_mydb()` exhibits undefined behaviour because it doesn't call `va_end()` on `vobj` before it returns.

Comment: 1. Thanks for pointing out the many bugs.   
2. You mean to say va_list operates on current function context only?  
3. I'd planned to use this concept (if it worked) to implement deferred work handling using pthreads and queue of work-contexts with variable arguments depending on work. Any pointers to help the cause?

Comment: 1. YW.  2. Yes.  3. You are going to have to devise a different mechanism.  Maybe an array of a 'universal type' (a discriminated union containing all the relevant types).  You can use variadic code to parse the arguments and copy them into a (dynamically allocated) array, which is then put in the work queue for threads to collect.  Fiddly — but not impossible.

Comment: Thanks again. I'll try as suggested.